# How to remove from array the key with duplicate ID and negative quantity

Tags: php, arrays

i got a multidimensional array that stores data for a specific products.But when the program removes it I receive new data with product that got quantity (ex. 1) and same product with quantity (-1).How can i remove from array both of them.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["I_ART"]=>
    string(14) "Еспресо"
    ["N_ART"]=>
    int(405)
    ["C_ART"]=>
    string(5) "1.900"
    ["Q_ART"]=>
    string(7) "-1.0000"
    ["MASA"]=>
    int(5)
    ["POR"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["I_ART"]=>
    string(8) "Фреш"
    ["N_ART"]=>
    int(363)
    ["C_ART"]=>
    string(5) "4.100"
    ["Q_ART"]=>
    string(6) "2.0000"
    ["MASA"]=>
    int(5)
    ["POR"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["I_ART"]=>
    string(14) "Еспресо"
    ["N_ART"]=>
    int(405)
    ["C_ART"]=>
    string(5) "1.900"
    ["Q_ART"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["MASA"]=>
    int(5)
    ["POR"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

In this array for example i want to remove the array key 0 and 2.Also the compare must be by N_ART number and Quantity difference 1 negative and 1 positive.
The expected output is

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["I_ART"]=>
    string(8) "Фреш"
    ["N_ART"]=>
    int(363)
    ["C_ART"]=>
    string(5) "4.100"
    ["Q_ART"]=>
    string(6) "2.0000"
    ["MASA"]=>
    int(5)
    ["POR"]=>
    int(1)
  }

}
```

Comment: You should provide and expected output :)

Comment: Have you tried using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) ?

Comment: I don't think array_filter cant handle my expectations

Comment: Can you include a var_export of the array instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

```
$newItems = [];

// Here you iterate over your source array and sum quantities under same `N_ART`
foreach ($sourceArray as $item) {
    $id = $item['N_ART'];

    if (!isset($newItems[$id])) {
        $newItems[$id] = $item;
    } else {
        $newItems[$id]['Q_ART'] += $item['Q_ART'];
    }
}
// Here you filter array so as to remove items where `Q_ART` is 0 or negative
$newItems = array_filter($newItems, function ($item) { return 0 < $item['Q_ART']; });
```